# Wordpress 3.0: Menu Question

Tags: wordpress, menu

HOw can you make a custom menu that goes to the home page but the url is not static? Like I am in a test server right now, so the url is localhost/mywordpress. I put a '/' in the url for my custom menu but it redirects to localhost.

Is there a way to put it in a way it can goes to the homepage of my test server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `/wordpress/` and remember to change it back on the production server.

Better yet, use Apache VirtualHosts to map a fake domain to a document root. Check out my answer on [setting up a VirtualHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098208/3101089#3101089).